# Finding a basis for the subsapces

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, change-of-basis

Trying to find the basis of these vector subspaces but I'm a little puzzled as to what I am trying to do. I've turned each of the equations for the subsapce into a matrix and tried to reduce it; I'm not sure how to read the basis off of it from that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've attached the question and my workings. Thank you very much!
[image: question and workings]

Comment: Choose some arbitrary values for your parameters so that the resulting vectors are nonzero and linearly independent, thereby getting a (minimal) spanning set for the subspace, such a spanning set is a basis for that space (likely not an orthonormal basis though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $S_1$ you have found, correctly, that a vector $(x,y,z)^T$ of $S_1$ is such that:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
2y-z\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}=
y\begin{pmatrix}
2\\1\\0
\end{pmatrix}+
z\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so a basis for $S_1$ is the couple of vectors $\{(2,1,0)^T,(-1,0,1)^T\}$. Note that $S_1$ is the plane passing thorough the origin and orthogonal to the vector $(1,-2,1)$ , so it has dimension $2$,  and that  $(0,0,0)^T$ is an element of any vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For $S_2$ note that it is the intersection of two non parallel planes , so it is a straight line ( dimension $1$):
$$
\begin{cases}
x-2y+z=0\\
x-z=0
\end{cases}
$$
from the second equation we have $x=z$ and, substituting in the first equation, we find $2y=2z \iff y=z$, so the line has the equation:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
=z\begin{pmatrix}
1\\1\\1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the vector $(1,1,1)^T$ is a basis for $S_2$,

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate your kind help! :)

Comment: Ah yes I didn't reduce the matrix properly for S2.